# Changing column layout css

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I am currently working on this website page: https://no.aproposonline.dk/brugte-biler/

as it is right now the page splits the search results into 2 columns, however i would like it to be split into 3, which is proving rather difficult.

I have tried `column-count:3` which does not work, it seems as if on columns is two rows, which I don't really know how to fix.

Comment: As a reminder, the Wordpress tag is for programming-specific questions about the WordPress content management system.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.bdt .col-lg-4 {
    flex: 0 0 30% !important;
    max-width: 30% !important;
}
}
```